# Проблема на шаге rake generate_secret_token при установке Redmine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems, redmine

Ошибка 1:

```
Could not find mysql2-0.4.9-x86-mingw32 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Ошибка 2:

```
Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\mysql2-0.4.9-x
86-mingw32\vendor\libmysql.dll
```

Перепробовал уже кучу всего:
`gem uninstall mysql2` с последующим

```
C:\ruby\redmine-3.4.2>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C
:\ruby\mysql-connector\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\ruby\mysql-connectorinclude
" --with-mysql-dir="C:\ruby\mysql-connector"'
```

После этого ошибка 1.
И просто удалить и делать ещё раз `bundle install`
Потом ругается см. ошибка 2.
Ничего не помогает... либо я не правильно готовлю.
Может кто ни будь подсказать?

Comment: Артем, добрый день!
Кто-нибудь помог тебе с вопросом?

Comment: Артем, добрый день!
Кто-нибудь помог тебе с вопросом?

Comment: Нет, в итоге поставил готовое решение от Bitnami https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine

Comment: Но если вы решите все траблы, то с удовольствием почитал бы полный и работоспособный гайд от вас по установке с 0